# How to get token and use in another page in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

My app needs to login, then get the token to access the data. I already succeeded to get the token from the response but my question is how to store the token and then use the token on another page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`shared_preferences`](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences#-readme-tab-):

in pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.6+2
```

After getting the token:

```
addTokenToSF() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setString('token', token);
}
```

To retrieve the token:

```
getTokenFromSF() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String tokenValue = prefs.getString('token');
  return tokenValue;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. How to use the token in sharedPreferences for my HTTP request?

Comment: Aren't u retrieving the token from ur response after authentication? Just call a method (after retrieving) that saves it to the shared preference. When you want to do another HTTP request just retrieve the token using `grtString()` and assign it to a variable and use it in the request header

Comment: Sir, where should I put the sharePreferences? I try to put in Future<User> login there but have error

Comment: undefined token

Comment: token is the token u are retrieving from the response...Where are you retrieving the token in the response? *I already success get the token from the response*?

Comment: I get the response from API is like this {"token":"token"}  . I can just declare var token = response.body?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208354/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-dipgirl).